# How should I interpret the phrase "f is applied to x" in function f(x) in math?

Tags: meaning, mathematics, definition

How should I interpret the phrase "f is applied to x" in function f(x) in math?

I found the expression:

> f (x) (i.e. f applied to x)

inside the math book.

I only have the 3 definitions of "apply" so far. Following three are the example-sentences for it:

1. ***He applied for a job.***
2. ***This math can be applied on practical stuff.***
3. ***Rule 3 can be applied to help you.***

So in the first expression of a function seems definitely cannot be applied to interpret the exact meaning of "f applied to x".

BTW for me, the expression "x is applied to f" seems plausible X0 (but of course this expression is wrong).

I need your help.

Comment: Why don't definitions 2 or 3 look appropriate to you?  To apply the function on a variable means to use it, like you use math for practical stuff, or use rule 3 to help you.

Comment: By the way, if those example sentences are copied correctly, they are bad examples of grammar.  *Stuff* is not countable, so it should be "on practical stuff", and *rule 3* should not take an article.

Comment: Edited the example sentences by your corrections. I had wrote the examples with my original ideas :D

Comment: I don't understand your question. I'm assuming you already understand what "f(x)" means. "f is applied to x" means the same thing.

Comment: Math usually uses some words in its own way, what we need to do is just remember the examples and mimic.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_application

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding the dictionary definition **please post the dictionary definition**. But meanings of mathematical terms are not always in a regular dictionary, and you need a mathematical dictionary or encyclopedia.

Comment: all the dictionaries I checked have some variation on "to make use of for a practical purpose," which is exactly what *applying* a function is: making use of the function for a practical purpose (to transform x in some way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply cream to the skin, or you can apply pressure with your thumb to a wound.  In these general uses you apply "some active thing" to "a passive receiver".  You use the cream on the skin.

In maths, the function is "active" (it maps elements of the domain to the codomain) and the variable "x" is "passive" (it has a value but doesn't do anything).  Hence you apply the function to the variable.

The analogy is you use "f" on "x".

Answer (score 3):

The verb *to apply* here isn't being used in a general, figurative sense that you would find in the dictionary, but in a technical sense. In mathematics, *to apply* a function is to retrieve the value that corresponds to the given argument.

Wikipedia [*Function (mathematics)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition):

> A function, its domain, and its codomain, are declared by the notation *f*: *X*→*Y*, and the value of a function *f* at an element *x* of *X*, denoted by *f(x)*, is called the *image* of *x* under *f*, or the *value* of *f* **applied** to the *argument* *x*.